# insert error to database from a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried inserting some license generated kes from a for loop into the database but I was getting Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys)values('46F2-SH73-2QDD-Z4VH-HV')' at line 1

I have been on it for sometime now trying to fiure it but it gives the same error everytime I run it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//ob_start();
//session_start();
//error_reporting(0);
//ini_set('display_errors', '0');
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');   
#$db = parse_ini_file("../config/db.ini");
$dbhost = 'localhost'; //$db['host'];
$dbuser = 'root';//$db['user'];
$dbpass = '';//$db['pass'];
$dbname = 'infonetsch_mgmt';//$db['dbname'];

//Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("MySQLi connection failed: ", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} 
// Change character set to utf8
if (!$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
    printf('Error loading character set utf8: %s\n', $mysqli->error);
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>License Key Generator</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F0F0F0">
<h1>License Key generation</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Keys to generate</td>
<td><select name="numkeys">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="5000">5000</option>
        <option value="10000">10000</option>
        <option value="20000">20000</option>
        <option value="50000">50000</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Length of Key</td>
<td><select name="keylen">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input name="validate" type="submit" value="Generate!"/>
</table>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['validate'])){
    $name= 'a';//$_POST['client'];
    $software= 'sis';//$_POST['software'];
    $numkeys=$_POST['numkeys']; if($numkeys<1)$numkeys=1; if($numkeys>50000)$numkeys=50000;
    $keylen=$_POST['keylen'];if($keylen<1)$keylen=1; if($keylen>20)$keylen=20;

include("license_key.class.php");

$pass=new license_key();
echo "<h3>Generating $numkeys Random License Keys </h3>
 KeyLenght: $keylen</a><hr/>";

for($i=0;$i<$numkeys;$i++){
    $pass->keylen=$keylen;
    $key= $pass->codeGenerate($name.$software);
    $get = mysqli_query($mysqli, "insert into license_keys(keys)values('".$key."')");//Insert query

    $j=$i+1;

    echo "$j- $key <br/>";


}
if($get){
echo "Done";    
}else{ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);; }
echo "<br/><br/><a href=\"test.php\">Generate again</a><br/><br/>";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting such an error?

Comment: what is the filed type for value in your db is it varchar or text?

Comment: on your for loop could you please echo the $get and then die and  show me the query please?

Comment: i think if you echo the $get query then you will find out what was the query. and i think in your query there are no space between table name and field name.

Comment: @rowmoin, varchar. I have already echo it out which is the error I told you it was displaying

Comment: could you please echo $get and then die and run the code and give me the query.

Comment: for($i=0;$i<$numkeys;$i++){ 
    $pass->keylen=$keylen;
    $key= $pass->codeGenerate($name.$software);echo "insert into license_keys(keys)values('".$key."')";die;
    $get = mysqli_query($mysqli, "insert into license_keys(keys)values('".$key."')");//Insert query

    $j=$i+1;

    echo "$j- $key <br/>";


}

Comment: run that code and you will see the row query

Answer (score 1):

There could be some special charaters in your license keys.  Try using `prepare` statement with reference from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp as

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into license_keys (`keys`) values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $key);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

run that code and check your keys field varchar limit

```
   <?php
        //ob_start();
        //session_start();
        //error_reporting(0);
        //ini_set('display_errors', '0');
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');   
        #$db = parse_ini_file("../config/db.ini");
        $dbhost = 'localhost'; //$db['host'];
        $dbuser = 'root';//$db['user'];
        $dbpass = '';//$db['pass'];
        $dbname = 'infonetsch_mgmt';//$db['dbname'];

        //Connect
        $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("MySQLi connection failed: ", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        } 
        // Change character set to utf8
        if (!$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
            printf('Error loading character set utf8: %s\n', $mysqli->error);
        }

        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>License Key Generator</title>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:#F0F0F0">
        <h1>License Key generation</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Keys to generate</td>
        <td><select name="numkeys">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="500">500</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="5000">5000</option>
                <option value="10000">10000</option>
                <option value="20000">20000</option>
                <option value="50000">50000</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Length of Key</td>
        <td><select name="keylen">
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        <input name="validate" type="submit" value="Generate!"/>
        </table>
        </form>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['validate'])){
            $name= 'a';//$_POST['client'];
            $software= 'sis';//$_POST['software'];
            $numkeys=$_POST['numkeys']; if($numkeys<1)$numkeys=1; if($numkeys>50000)$numkeys=50000;
            $keylen=$_POST['keylen'];if($keylen<1)$keylen=1; if($keylen>20)$keylen=20;

        include("license_key.class.php");

        $pass=new license_key();
        echo "<h3>Generating $numkeys Random License Keys </h3>
         KeyLenght: $keylen</a><hr/>";

        for($i=0;$i<$numkeys;$i++){
            $pass->keylen=$keylen;
            $key= $pass->codeGenerate($name.$software);
            $get = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO license_keys (keys) VALUES('".$key."')");//Insert query

            $j=$i+1;

            echo "$j- $key <br/>";


    }
    if($get){
    echo "Done";    
    }else{ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);; }
    echo "<br/><br/><a href=\"test.php\">Generate again</a><br/><br/>";

    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read the SQL error correctly.

MySQL is throwing an SQL syntax error, so your insert query has incorrect syntax.

```
insert into license_keys(`keys`) values(?)
```

Put a space between the license_keys(keys) and the 'values'

Also put backticks around the 'keys' column.

Comment: Thanks to you guys. The error was from the database - I made used of database reserved word "keys" so for that reason it refused to execute the query. I had to change the column name keys to license_keys.